# Imported tex file doesn't encode

Tags: input-encodings

I started typing in a latex template provided by my school. Inside the document, when I use special characters such as accents or umlauts (e.g. ë) they encode just fine. When I use an external file (`\input{file}`) it also encodes perfectly. I use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` in my main document.

But the document also imports an `abstract.tex` file using:

```
\abstractpagetrue
\abstracts{abstract}
```

**And in that file, I also have a lot of `ë` characters and they encode to `Ã«`**. That tex file only contains some raw text with no latex commands whatsoever.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: the file with the Ã« is almost certainly encoded in UTF-8 not latin1. Make sure that your editor is set to encode all the files in the same encoding, this can be UTF-8 or latin-1 but then you need the appropriate option to `inputenc`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't check the settings of the editor itself, only the latex settings. The editor was set to UTF-8. I changed it and now it encodes just right! Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file with the `Ã«` is almost certainly encoded in UTF-8 not latin1.

Make sure that your editor is set to encode all the files in the same encoding, this can be UTF-8 or latin-1 but then you need the appropriate option to `inputenc`.